# Error contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount

Tags: contract-deployment, javascript, metamask

I get an error: Error contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.

I know this error has been reported several times already. Strange thing is, until this morning, my dApp just worked fine, only this afternoon to start giving this error. I literally changed nothing.

I use metamask as wallet, you can find the project on oursurance.nl

Strange thing is that it deploys the contract and I can find the contract and similar coded contracts (that worked without a problem) through ehterscan. but still gives this error. To contract accounts now exist and bear ethers, but I can't interact with them.

Again, it has been working just fine and I haven't changed anything. I tried to add extra gas, but that didn't help. Hope anyone can help!

kind regards, Olivier

Comment: It is possibly an execution error in the constructor leading back to the process you use to deploy it. If the constructor can't execute without `throw;` it might bubble up as an "out-of-gas" error. That can happen if an expected parameter isn't present depending on how the constructor is designed.

Comment: Strange thing is that it deploys the contract and I can find similar coded contracts (that worked without a problem). but still gives this error. To contract accounts now exist and bear ethers, but I can't interact with them.

Comment: I am having the exact same [issue](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15705/when-creating-a-new-contract-i-receive-a-contract-code-couldnt-be-stored-erro)

Comment: After a few days, it was resolved. But I'm worried about the stability of ropsten, last Friday it as doing strange things again (deploying, but only after an hour etc).

Comment: @OlivierRikken What solved it?  Would be great if you could add that as an answer so others may find the solution to the problem.

Comment: Where did you find information on this hiccup? Or was it an assumption? I ask because I have basically the exact same experience as you and am currently having issues running migrations to ropsten. Worked fine for me last week... save complaints about gas/transactions still getting mined...

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be a hickup in Ropsten at that time. Problem solved itself.

Comment: This appears to be the correct answer. Simply re-running my deployment also fixed it for me (I am also on Ropsten).