# When creating a new contract I receive a "contract code couldn't be stored" error but the contract is still created

Tags: web3js, ether, truffle, ropsten, metamask

```
Sale.new({ from: state.account, value: value, gas: 4000000 }).then((instance) => {
  // do something with instance
}).catch((err) => {
  alert(err)
})
```

When the above code runs I sometimes receive this error: `The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.`

The contract I am trying to create is almost exactly the same as the [safe remote payment](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/solidity-by-example.html) contract in the solidity docs with maybe just a few more lines.

The weird thing is that the contract actuallygets created and I can see the successful transaction in MetaMask and the Ether is subtracted from my account. I can even then use `Sale.at(<new contract address>)` to interact with the created contract. I've been testing in the Ropsten network.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you didn't mention here is that previously this worked fine, but about a week ago this stopped working.

This makes me think it's a bug with MetaMask, and I'm sorry we haven't gotten to figure it out yet:
https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-plugin/issues/1361

Answer (score 1):

This feels like one of those very broad errors. I encountered it when I added a function argument without updating my ABI file (I keep function definitions and functions in separate files) - this led to the function definition being inconsistent with the implementation.

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: This was my problem with this error message. I had added a function to the abstract contract, but not to the implemented contract.

Answer (score 0):

you got the error after the exception thrown in the constructor.

i think there is something wrong with this snippet :

```
  function Purchase() payable {
        seller = msg.sender;
        value = msg.value / 2;
        if (2 * value != msg.value) throw;
    }
```

it's likely to throw an exception while `2*value==msg.value`.

Comment: Why is it likely to throw an exception? And it this throws then shouldn't the transaction be rolled back? Why does it get created successfully?

Comment: what's value you send in the creation transaction?

Comment: The user will type in something like 0.1. Which is then ran through

`web3.toWei(web3.toBigNumber(0.1).times(2), 'ether')`

So I would think that the constructor should be able to divide the value sent equally into 2 parts because it was multiplied by 2 before being sent.